# Arithmetic operations with large numbers in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I got a task to write an assembly routine that can be read from C and declared as follows:

```
extern int solve_equation(long int a, long  int b,long  int c, long int *x, long int *y);
```

that finds a solution to the equation

```
a * x + b * y = c
```

In `-2147483648 <x, y <2147483647` by checking all options.

The value returned from the routine will be `1` if a solution is found and another `0`.

You must take into consideration that the results of the calculations: `a * x, b * y, a * x + b * y` can exceed 32 bits.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
C DQ ?
SUM DQ 0
MUL1 DQ ?
MUL2 DQ ?
X DD ?
Y DD ?
.CODE
.386
PUBLIC _solve_equation
_solve_equation PROC NEAR
PUSH BP 
MOV BP,SP
PUSH SI
MOV X,-2147483648 
MOV Y,-2147483648 
MOV ECX,4294967295
FOR1:
        CMP ECX,0
        JE FALSE
        PUSH ECX
        MOV Y,-2147483648 
        MOV ECX,4294967295
FOR2:
        MOV SUM,0
        CMP ECX,0
        JE SET_FOR1

        MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [BP+4]
        IMUL X
        MOV DWORD PTR MUL1,EAX
        MOV DWORD PTR MUL1+4,EDX

        MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [BP+8]
        IMUL Y
        MOV DWORD PTR MUL2,EAX
        MOV DWORD PTR MUL2+4,EDX

        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR MUL1
        ADD DWORD PTR SUM,EAX
        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR MUL2
        ADD DWORD PTR SUM,EAX

        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR MUL1+4
        ADD DWORD PTR SUM+4,EAX
        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR MUL2+4
        ADD DWORD PTR SUM+4,EAX

        CMP SUM,-2147483648
        JL SET_FOR2
        CMP SUM,2147483647
        JG SET_FOR2
        MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [BP+12]
        CMP DWORD PTR SUM,EAX
        JE TRUE
SET_FOR2:       
            DEC ECX
            INC Y
            JMP FOR2
SET_FOR1:
            POP ECX
            DEC ECX
            JMP FOR1
FALSE:
            MOV AX,0
            JMP SOF
TRUE:
            MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+16]
            MOV EAX,X
            MOV DWORD PTR [SI],EAX
            MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+18]
            MOV EAX,Y   
            MOV DWORD PTR [SI],EAX
            MOV AX,1
SOF:
        POP SI
        POP BP
        RET
        _solve_equation ENDP
        END
```

Is this the right way to work with large numbers?

I get argument to operation or instruction `has illegal size` when I try to do:

```
MOV SUM,0
CMP SUM,-2147483648
CMP SUM,2147483647
```

main code:

```css
int main() 
    {
     long int x, y, flag;

     flag = solve_equation(-5,4,2147483647,&x, &y);
    if (flag == 1)
      printf("%ld*%ld + %ld*%ld = %ld\n", -5L,x,4L,y,2147483647);
      return 0;

    }
```

output

```css
-5*-2147483647 + 4*-2147483647 = 2147483647
```

I`m using dosbox 0.74 and tcc

Comment: Note that even in asm, this might take some while to run. A very long while.

Comment: Looks like a mixed-source program (TurboC and TASM?). Please add the appropriate tags and describe what versions you use. Show the main program. Is the parameter list (`int c! int*x ,int*y!`) determined by the teacher?

Comment: @rkhb  yes,the parameter list  determined by the teacher,and i did the changes peter said and it works.

Comment: If it works, it's fine. Please consider each time my request: additional tags ([tag:turbo-c] or [tag:turbo-c++], [tag:tasm] and [tag:dosbox]), main program and specification of the TurboC version. These informations help enormously to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using 16-bit code, so 64-bit operand-size isn't available.  Your assembler magically associates a size with `sum`, because you defined it with `sum dq 0`.

So `mov sum, 0` is equivalent to `mov qword ptr [sum], 0`, which of course won't assemble in 16 or 32-bit mode;  you can only operate on up to 32 bits at once with integer operations.

(32-bit operand-size is available in 16-bit mode on 386-compatible CPUs, using the same machine encodings that allows 16-bit operand size in 32-bit mode.  But 64-bit operand size is only available in 64-bit mode.  Unlike 386, AMD64 didn't add any new prefixes or anything to previously-existing modes, for various reasons.)

---

You could zero the whole 64-bit `sum` with an SSE store, or even compare with [SSE4.2 `pcmpgtq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPGTQ.html), but that's probably not what you want.

It looks like you want to check if 64-bit `sum` fits in 32 bits.  (i.e. if it is a sign-extended 32-bit integer).

So really you just need to check that all 32 high bits are the same and match bit 31 of the low half.

```
mov  eax, dword ptr [sum]
cdq                              ; sign extend eax into edx:eax
                                 ; i.e. copy bit 31 of EAX to all bits of EDX
cmp  edx, dword ptr [sum+4]
je   small_sum
```

Comment: Can we use SSE under DOS? IIRC we need to set a few bits in the control registers before using the SSE extensions.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Yes, you can use SSE in real mode, but not AVX.  16-bit mode disables decoding of VEX prefixes to avoid breaking the use of that encoding as a trap, apparently.  I assume DOS wouldn't set the control-register bits for you, but you can do so (https://wiki.osdev.org/SSE).  (I wrote this answer before noticing that it was 16-bit code, rather than the 32-bit I was thinking).